# Queueable apex duration time issue

Tags: apex, batch, queueable-apex

I'm running a Queueable that upsert contacts (in my example case it's just two contacts) and calling a batch with a Map < Id,String > - which Id is the Id of the upserted contacts, and the String is a serialized JSON for each contact.

What I see in my logs is the next thing which it's a little strange :

[image]

1237107834 ms is 20618 Minutes which is 343 Hours... It does not make sense, especially the batch called and ran In a flash.

The command I'm running is :

```
ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new StudentFileQuable());
```

And at the end of my process I'm running the batch call.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed it too, it's been like that for ages. I am guessing something in Salesforce's implementation doesn't work well with date handling as it's async process. Hope you do not really need to rely to it in your business logic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no SLA for asynchronous process as to when it will execute or
>   finish.

This means Salesforce would decide when it will run, and if  your instance is shared with a big client that uses a lot of Async Apex, it's you who would get a penalty for it.

I have seen 24 hours to execute a future job. You should raise with SF support, I have seen jobs get queued infinitely in sanboxes.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320538&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I just want to understand the difference between this decision in the different async jobs. On future call, for example, it's a normal duration time - This is shouldn't be the same?

Comment: There is no priority between async jobs.. they all have no SLA and no priority over one another, its randomly decided by SF.